# FireFox browser control in visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, browser

Is there a way to use firefox engine for the "web browser control" instead of internet explorers engine in visual studio 2010 .NET 3.5 or 4?

Comment: Do you mean the window from "View/Other Windows/Web Browser", not the browser to load programmed web pages? I would be interested too.

Comment: I mean the web control of visual studio 2010 that is emedid in the framework of studio. I wish to change this and add a firefox engine instead of internet explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Mozilla ActiveX control](http://www.adamlock.com/mozilla/) with an API identical to the IE control.

Comment: I think this will do. I will test it and come back later

Comment: Unfortunately that link is broken now and everywhere else advertising to download it looks dodgy as

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen a FireFox control but I have used the Chrome one before and it works a treat.

Solved a load of issues that I was having with the default IE control.

http://awesomiumdotnet.codeplex.com/

It might not be for you if you NEED Firefox specifically...but worth a look.